# компилятор и IDE для С++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, ide

Существует IDE который поддерживает C++ и C#.При этом можно компилировать.
Есть на примете Atom.Но на нем нету нормального C#.
Но при этом ресурсоемкие.А то Visual Studia много потребляет.

Comment: visual studio code

Comment: Visual Studio потребляет меньше, чем атом VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

вы про IDE или редакторы кода ? IDE всё же более функциональны и монструозны в плане потребления ресурсов, но и дают кучу плюшек облегчающих работу.

- IDE - Visual Studio , Intellij Lion
- Редакторы - Atom, VS code, Sublime Text, Notepad++

ведь код можно писать в чем угодно, вопрос в потребностях. Чем больше проект, тем сложнее его ковырять блокнотом, те же дебагеры, профилировщики и прочие спец. инструменты зачастую отсутствуют в редакторах, в них есть много плагинов и вам предстоит собрать для себя велосипед, а потом ехать.